# cannot resolve class name 'InvocationMirror' in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I've been trying to use Dart's `noSuchMethod()`, but this code

```dart
noSuchMethod(InvocationMirror invocation) {
  // ...
}
```

results in the following error: `cannot resolve class name 'InvocationMirror' from 'MyClass'`

It looks like there's no such class as InvocationMirror. Could it be an older version of dart which doesn't have it? The one I have is the stable one from SDK for Mac downloaded just today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're observing an inconsistency between specification and implementation (which shouldn't come as a surprise, there are a lot of them). You can use `noSuchMethod`, at least on Dart VM (don't know about dart2js), but it looks like this: `noSuchMethod(String name, List arguments)`. In the future, when reflection finally comes to Dart, it will change.

Answer (score 2):

You can currently not use the **InvocationMirror** class as mirror based reflection is not yet implemented in Dart (as mentioned in [this](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/) article).